# Bootstrap fixed table width for wide table

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I got stuck with the design of my bootstrap table. The table data gets dynamically generated, containing up to 500 columns, that is one for each position in a sequence. 
First, I tried to find a solution to wrap the columns into multiple rows, but I was not successful, then I decided to create multiple tables.

The last table contains the remaining columns and I want them to have the same column width as the previous columns, which appears to be quite tricky in bootstrap, css style max-width does not work. Maybe you know a solution ? Thanks.

Below is a kind of minimal working example which shows the problem.

```
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <title>Table</title>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <!--<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1">-->
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style>
            .table-bordered thead tr th{
                text-align: center;
                table-layout: fixed;
                width: 10px;
                max-width: 10px;
                background-color: grey;
            }

            .table-bordered tbody tr td{
                text-align: center;
                width: 10px;
                max-width: 10px;
}

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class = "container">
            <div class = "row">
                <div class = "col-md-12">

                    <form role = "form" method = "post" action = "">
                        <?php
                        $posvector = range(0, 25);
                        $poschunks = array_chunk($posvector, 10);

                        foreach ($poschunks as $chunk) {

                            echo ' <table class="table table-bordered"> ';
                            echo ' <thead> ';
                            echo ' <tr> ';
                            foreach ($chunk as $p) {
                                echo ' <th> ' . $p . ' </th> ';
                            }
                            echo ' </tr> ';
                            echo ' </thead> ';
                            echo '<tbody> ';

                            for ($i = 0; $i < count($chunk); $i++) {
                                echo '  <td>  <input type="radio" name="posradio" value="'
                                . $i . '"> </td>  ';
                            }
                            echo ' </tr> ';
                            echo ' </tbody> ';
                            echo ' </table> ';
                            echo ' <br> ';
                        }
                        ?>



                        <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit_pos" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use class table-bordered without table then it should work. Class table is responsible for covering the entire view.

```
echo ' <table class="table-bordered"> ';
```